# Broken functions.php; how to Move scripts From bootstrap into WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and WordPress and trying to put together a simple page. So, it doesn't surprise me that I'm running into dependency problems adding and registering scripts from both the header and footer.

Is there anything obvious here that I'm missing?

```
<?php 

function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{

// register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );     
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-tweet', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery.tweet.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'clock', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/clock.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
    wp_register_script( 'soon', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/soon.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

//footer scripts     
    wp_register_script( 'dat-gui-min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/dat.gui.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'fss', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/fss.js');
    wp_register_script( 'bgCustom', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bgCustom.js');


// For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script','jquery-tweet','clock','soon','dat-gui-min-js','fss','bgCustom');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );

?>
```

and

in header.php

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Comment: Just a heads up.. You don't need <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?> in the header anymore. WP automatically loads the latest jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need a unique name for each script you register with `wp_register_script`.  For example, you are naming all of them 'custom_script'.  I would name each one the same name as its JavaScript file (just for convenience).  So for example...

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery-tweet', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery.tweet.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_register_script( 'clock', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/clock.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

... etc.  Then you would enqueue each one like this...

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-tweet' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'clock' );
```

... etc.

Hope that helps, have fun!

Comment: Not sure if it's important, but possibly place them within an `add_action` function so they're hooked in the right place, not just at `functions.php` load.

Comment: Yep, exactly correct.  (My snippets won't work as is... They're just snippets from the context of OP's code, so the `add_action` call is still required.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: thank you, i'll keep trying. For the add_action... is this different than 
    <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

Comment: @Charles No, it's where you have to *encase* the `wp_enqueue_script(s)`

Comment: @Charles You can keep your code *as you posted it originally*, just change each `wp_register_script` function call to have a unique name (as the answer makes note) and be sure to call `wp_enqueue_script` for each one.  In your first post, you have the `add_action` function built the right way.

Comment: @JaredCobb Sorry! I only just noticed the OP post, `add_action` was not within the script block, but shown as normal text - ignore me! sorry again! =)

Comment: @MackieeE np, I submitted a format change to the code block so maybe it'll be more readable.  :)

Comment: great.almost cracked it.

Comment: @Charles Try putting all of your `wp_enqueue_script` function calls *inside* your `wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()` function (rather than in your `header.php` file). I usually place mine at the end so that they're easy to find, just after those `wp_register_script` function calls.

Comment: ok, that makes a lot more sense, what should I do after so the header to calls the JS?  Another newbie question, since I'm working from a purchased bootstrap template, I'm not really sure if certain scripts are dependent upon jquery,  so not sure if it's right to put it in the array. Going forward I should 1. Alter the WP_register to the WP_enqueue 2. remove the possible dependencies, except for the first two were clearly need Jquery. 3.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );  Can be altered because I'm calling the scripts above 4.…

Comment: @Charles The `get_header` function in your `header.php` will automatically run the function. It won't hurt anything to require jQuery as a dependency for the other scripts that don't *technically* need it.

Comment: I'm closing this question, because there are several different issues.

Comment: A better written and explained question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021626/bootstrap-into-wordpress-js-dependencies